# Oracle - grant non-dba user rigths to create grants on another user objects

Tags: oracle

Is there any possibility to grant regular user on Oracle database privilege to grant access to table in another schema? Due to security policy in our company I cannot simply grant dba nor sysdba privilege to this user, because I can find many such solutions. My goal is to create special account with credentials known only to administrators who could perform some dba operations and not elevate regular user privileges.

I need something like:

- we have user1, user2 and user3
- we grant some special privileges to user1
- now we can execute as user1: **grant select on user2.table1 to user3**

Any thoughts on how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`GRANT` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603) you have the option to use the qualifier [`WITH GRANT OPTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF55031):

> Specify WITH GRANT OPTION to enable the grantee to grant the object privileges to other users and roles.

i.e. if USER1 grants SELECT to USER2 and you want USER2 to be able to propagate that grant to USER3 you would use the following while connected as USER1

```
grant select on user1.table to user2 with grant option
```

You can then do the following while connected as USER2

```
grant select on user1.table to user3
```

Comment: Ben, thanks for answer but this is not exactly my case, please note that. I wish to have one account to perform all the tasks, I prefer not to switch to other accounts.

Comment: @RLapinski the answer given is correct.You want a super user without granting super user ability. If that was possible it would violate every security constraint built into the database. What you are seeing above is actually pretty common.

Comment: Actually I've manage to solve my issue with different approach without need of special account. But I'll accept the solution if you say so :)

Comment: I didn't say so @RLapinski and if you have a different answer why don't you post it so that others can learn in the future?

Comment: Understood. I've just eliminated the need of user1 from my example and I'm working only with user2 to execute grants.